# DateTime is not excluded when CultureInfo.InvariantCulture using

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have used like this,

[image]

```
string subscriptionCurrectPeriodStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(subscriptionCurrectPeriodStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

But seconds are not excluded. Please suggest me to fix this.

it throws "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." exception.

Comment: Please clarify the question. What do you expect to get and what do you get instead? Where are they not excluded?

Comment: Why are you converting a date to a string, only to parse it again, and then call ToString? What is the benefit? Do you not simply want `string subscriptionCurrectPeriodStartDate = subscriptionCurrectPeriodStart.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer the below MSDN link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

And also you may try:

```
subscriptionCurrectPeriodStart.ToString("g");
```

Comment: Now i facing exception. Please refer my updated code.

Comment: @Gokul You need to format your subscriptionCurrectPeriodStart in correct DateTime and post that just try using 'subscriptionCurrectPeriodStart.ToString("g"); ' to remove seconds as mentioned in my answer